# Spanish.ldf error

Tags: errors, babel, spanish

I just installed MiKTeX 2.9 x64 on my windows 8.1 laptop. I use Texmaker as a TeX editor.

I'm trying to compile a document with these packages:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage[spanish]{layout}
```

when the compiler is running, it appears the MiKTeX Package Manager's message saying that the file `spanish.ldf` is missing and it will install the `babel-spanish` package. So, I click yes, then the package is installed, but I get the following error: (and hundred more)

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.117 \StartBabelCommands
```

on line 117 but my file only has 67 lines!.

On the other hand, if I compile the file clicking on "no" to the package manager, the file compile normally.

How can I install the `babel-spanish` in order to compile normally my files?

I tried to install this package from differents repositories and I still get the error.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. You might also want to add to your question how you're including the pdfs etc.

Comment: `l.117 \StartBabelCommands` refers `spanish.ldf` file not to your `.tex` file.

Comment: Did you run the update manager (in admin and in user mode if you have a multiuser installation)?

Comment: I presume what you need is to install a recent version of `babel`.

Comment: I have the same problem, it seems not to be related with the code, because 2 different files give the same error. Those files contained different stuff on the line 117. And now I read this post about a document with less lines and the same error text.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an issue due to outdated software, solved by an update.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably care about the order of the package calls... I think you can't call `\usepackage{inputec}` BEFORE `\usepackage{babel}`... LaTeX needs to "know" first which language is going to use... I hope this fix your problem...

Cheers